# Access password in iOS Keychain

Tags: ios, password, keychain, twitter

I need to access a password stored in my iOS Keychain, but can't find a way to do that. I have full access to my devices, it's passcode and all of my backups.

The password I'm looking stored by the Twitter app. Long story but I changed my password, forgot it and lost access to the email associated with the account. Twitter won't allow me to reset, but the Twitter app on my iPhone still has access.

There has to be a way to access the iOS Keychain. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Related question: Dumping a keychain to a plain text file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717095/is-there-a-quick-and-easy-way-to-dump-the-contents-of-a-macos-x-keychain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Twitter app should not actually have your password stored on your iOS device.  Rather it should have a security token, specifically an OAuth access token.

Have you tried [resetting your password via SMS](https://support.twitter.com/articles/14663)?

Comment: The OAuth token makes sense, but I thought I read somewhere that the twitter password is stored now due to the integration of twitter with iOS 5. I just added a new account to my app and the app itself asked for the p/w and didn't take me to the normal twitter OAuth page. I'm going to assume you're right, though. I need closer on this! And thanks for the SMS suggestion. Unfortunately my phone is registered to another account.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the app in question stores the password in retrievable form in the keychain, but with iOS 7, you can enable keychain sync on iOS and have that information synced through iCloud to a Mac running Mavericks.

From there, you can inspect the iCloud keychain contents just like any other OS X keychain and obtain clear text password as well as any other data stored in the keychain entry.

Comment: It seems like this "sync" is only one-way, from ios to mac, is that correct?  On iOS (Safari -> Saved Passwords) I see five passwords but on my mac (Keychain Access) I see dozens.